# Small differences in expected/actual values on a integer leading to a assertEquals fails

Tags: java

I'm writing a automated test confirm the sku/cart value is correct when eg a SKU * Quantity = total. Sometimes (on particular regional versions of same site epsacily ) the test will fail as there's small differences in the decimal values Eg

(in this case the quantity was 20, the sku value was 33.92 with a expected total of 678.40)

**java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :678.3999633789062
Actual   :678.4000244140625**

Obviously the calculation is going off at some point but still being very close, also its unnecessary for the calculation to be done to more than 2 decimal places.

I have tried limit the number of decimals places being used in the methods which get the values for quantity and price from elements before  Assert.assertEquals does the calculation of the unit price and the quantity compared to total to no avail. Mainly using .NumberFormat in the 'get' value methods

This is the code for the Cucumber/Gherkin step

```java
@Then("^the SKU cart Price reflects the unit price times the quantity value$")
    public void theSKUCartPriceReflectsTheUnitPriceTimesTheQuantityValue() {
        itemsInTheBasket_page.waitForCalcResult();
System.out.println(itemsInTheBasket_page.getfirstcartQuantityValue());     System.out.println(itemsInTheBasket_page.getUnitPriceOfFirstItemInCart());
System.out.println(itemsInTheBasket_page.getfirstCartItemPriceValue());
Assert.assertEquals(itemsInTheBasket_page.getfirstcartQuantityValue() * itemsInTheBasket_page.getUnitPriceOfFirstItemInCart(), itemsInTheBasket_page.getfirstCartItemPriceValue(), 0.0);
    }
``


And the code for the for methods used above

 public void waitForCalcResult() {
        Waits.clickable(driver, costCalcResult, 10);
    }


public int getfirstcartQuantityValue() {
        Waits.visible(driver, firstCartItemQuantityField, 5);
        return Integer.parseInt(firstCartItemQuantityField.getAttribute("value"));

    }

public float getUnitPriceOfFirstItemInCart() {
        Waits.visible(driver,firstCartSKUUnitPriceValue, 5);
        String unitValue = firstCartSKUUnitPriceValue.getText();
        unitValue = unitValue.replaceFirst(",", ".");
        unitValue = unitValue.replaceFirst(" ", "");
        unitValue = unitValue.replaceFirst("€", "");
        unitValue = unitValue.replaceAll("[$]", "");
        unitValue = unitValue.replaceAll("£", "");
        return Float.valueOf(unitValue);
    }

 public float getfirstCartItemPriceValue() {
        Waits.visible(driver,firstCartItemPriceValue,5);
        String PriceValue = firstCartItemPriceValue.getText();
        PriceValue = PriceValue.replaceFirst(",", ".");
        PriceValue = PriceValue.replaceFirst(" ", "");
        PriceValue = PriceValue.replaceFirst("€", "");
        PriceValue = PriceValue.replaceAll("[$]", "");
        PriceValue = PriceValue.replaceAll("£", "");
        return Float.valueOf(PriceValue);
    }
```

Comment: The real problem here is that you're using floats to represent currency.  Don't.  You'll always have issues with rounding.  It's recommended to use BigDecimal for currency.

Comment: What do you think the `0.0` means, the third parameter of `assertEquals`?

Comment: @AndyTurner the first value is basically quantity*unit price, and its making sure that equals whats the total

Comment: @Jordan Is that still necessary as i've extracted the symbols for currency from the values so it surely is just another int/float ? Would changing to big decimals fix the issue I'm having as well as being bet practice. Also how should I change my methods to use big decimals?

Comment: @LeonTilbrook As soon as you do *any* arithmetic on a float, you're going to have rounding errors.  In your assertion, you do floating-point multiplication, so your result is not going to be what you expect.  For instance, you may expect 2.0 * 2.0 to be 4.0, but will discover that the actual result is something like 3.999999998.  This is, unfortunately, perfectly normal for floating-point arithmetic.  BigDecimals have no rounding errors.  Take a look at the [javadoc for BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to see how they're used.

Comment: Floating point is an approximation of a sum of powers of 2. **BigDecimal** though a bit verbose in usage is a rock solid solution (fixed point numbers). https://netjs.blogspot.com/2017/04/bigdecimal-in-java.html